# Don't show empty field in rails4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<p>
  <% if @person.name %>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @person.name %>
  <% end %>
</p>

<p>
  <% if @person.gender %>
    <strong>Gender:</strong>
    <%= @person.gender %>
  <% end %>
</p>

<p>
  <% unless @person.age.blank? %>
    <strong>Age:</strong>
    <%= @person.age %>
  <% end %>
</p>

<p>
  <% unless @person.address.blank? %>
    <strong>Address:</strong>
    <%= @person.address %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

This code works fine. Its not showing empty field , but I want to know that is there any other way to do so. Because here I'm repeating same type of code again and again. Can I use any `helper` that stop showing empty fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, and the 'best' is dependent on your situation.  As long as the labels are always the same as the attributes, one way you could do it is in a simple partial:

```
#person/_attribute.html.erb    

<% if @person.public_send attribute != nil %>
  <strong><%= attribute.to_s.capitalize %></strong>
  <%= @person.public_send attribute %>
<% end %>
```

which would make your view look like this:

```
<p>
  <%= render 'attribute' :attribute => :name %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= render 'attribute' :attribute => :gender %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= render 'attribute' :attribute => :age %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= render 'attribute' :attribute => :address %>
</p>
```

I have to take this opportunity to preach HAML at you, though - your code *could* look like this!

```
#person/_attribute.haml

- if @person.public_send attribute != nil
  %strong= attribute.to_s.capitalize
  = @person.public_send attribute

#person/show.haml

%p= render 'attribute' :attribute => :name 
%p= render 'attribute' :attribute => :gender 
%p= render 'attribute' :attribute => :age
%p= render 'attribute' :attribute => :address
```